# Python if expression does not work correctly with raw input

Tags: python, if-statement, raw-input

This script does not progress passed the first if expression!
If the user enters DD, or F, the script acts as like the if state was true.

```
choice = raw_input("Cup size for bra: D, DD, or F: ")
if choice == "D" or "d":
    band_length = raw_input("Please enter the bra band length for your D size breasts: ")
    D_Statistics(band_length)
elif choice == "DD" or "dd":
    band_length = raw_input("Please enter the bra band length for your DD size breasts: ")
    DD_statistics(band_length)
elif choice == "F" or "f":
    band_length = raw_input("Please enter the bra band length for your F size breasts: ")
    F_statistics(band_length)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statements will always evaluate to `True` currently.

`if choice == "D" or "d"` evaluates to True on either the value of `choice` equaling "D", or the value of literal "d" being True; and the second part is thus always `True`.

Instead, use

```
if choice in ("D", "d"):
    ...
elif choice in ("DD", "dd"):
    ...
if choice in ("F", "f"):
    ...
```

Comment: choice.lower() or choice.upper() then test only once.

Comment: @RafaelBarros I don't think that will provide much advantage, calling a function will always be more costlier that using literals

Comment: I see your point, and I agree. Also: more costly.

Comment: thanks, i've been stuck all day on this.